# Minimum Privileges for vmware user for Foreman 1.4 Compute Resource

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, foreman

I am currently trying to add a ESXi cluster I have into Foreman 1.4.1, and am running into a problem with permissions. Currently, I've given a service account the following rights:

- Datacenter-Level:

  - Datastore -> Allocate Space
  - VM -> Inventory -> Create New
- Cluster-Level:

  - Datastore -> Allocate Space
  - Network -> Assign Network
  - Resource -> Assign virtual machine to Resource Pool
  - VM -> *

With that we still have issues with assigning interfaces to a Network, and I cannot create a disk for the specified machine. Does anyone know the minimum permissions necessary for foreman to provision on a vSphere cluster?

Comment: Good question. Did you ever figure this out?